# How can I enable color and scheme on Cmder ssh like it is usually?

Tags: ssh, colors, themes, cmder

I like to know if it is possible to change the theme or the color in Cmder, when I have a ssh connection? During the ssh everything is almost in white. But usually on Windows Cmder has its own theme or colors as you can see on the pictures.

Thank you

SSH Connection:
[image]

Cmder on Windows:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution how to color up this:

1. Go to ~/.bashrc file
2. Replace the lines from 52 to 62 with this code:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then                                                                           
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else                                                                                                         
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\e[1;32m\u@\h:\e[1;36m\w\e[0m\$ '                                 
fi                                                                                                           
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt                                                                        

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir                                                         
case "$TERM" in                                                                                              
xterm*|rxvt*)                                                                                                
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

This is the result:

[image: Cmder colored ssh connection]

For more color options you need to install colortest with:

```
sudo apt-get install colortest
```

and then to see the color code options:

```
colortest-16b
```

**To change the colors just edit the line 55.**